# HTML Table issue grabbing data from two database tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Iam having an issue getting data from two different database tables to display properly with in an HTML table. I'm sure I am just overlooking something and this is pretty easy, but for whatever reason I cannot get quantity to display, or the `<td class="sub-total">` to display either.

Demands (you can think of these as orders) and items are connected through a table called demand_items. The demand_items table also has the quantity of the item ordered. The page will display but the quantity and the subtotal will not render.

Here is the html:

```
<h3>Order for <%= @demand.customer.name %></h3>
<h4>Ordered for: <%= @demand.date %></h4>
<h4>Add Items</h4>

<%= render 'demands/item_form' %>

<table class="customer-table">
<tr>
    <th>Item</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Sub Total</th>
</tr>

<% @demand.items.each do |item| %>
<tr>
    <td><%= item.name %></td>
    <td><%= item.price %></td>
   <% @demand.demand_items do |quantity| %>
    <td><%= quantity.quantity %></td>
    <td class="sub-total"><%= (item.price) * (quantity.quantity) %></td>
    <% end %>
     <% end %>

</tr> 

</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

`@demand.demand_items.each do |quantity|..........`instead of  `@demand.demand_items do |quantity|......`

Comment: When I do that I get every item in the order on the same row so it ends up looking [like this](http://imgur.com/FDu6dwX)